# HashMultiMap save repetitive keys bindings on background?

Tags: f#, hashtable, powerpack

why when table.Count = 1 table iteration functions get more than 1 key-value pairs? 
And if this is feature how can I expected behavior?

```
//
            let table = new HashMultiMap<string, int> (HashIdentity.Structural)
            table.Add("a", 1)
            table.Add("a", 1)
            table.Add("a", 1)
            // now table.Count is one
            let reduced = table.Fold (fun k v acc -> (k,v) :: acc) [] 
            let acc = ref []
            table.Iterate (fun k v -> acc.contents <- (k,v) :: acc.contents)
            //
```

reduced and acc.contents contains three ("a",1) pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the `Count` member says:

> The total number of keys in the hash table

If you have multiple values associated with the same key, there is still only a single key, so the value 1 is the expected result for your example. As far as I can see, there is no property that returns the total number of *values*, but you can implement that easily using `Fold`:

```
let valueCount = table.Fold (fun _ _ n -> n + 1) 0
```

Comment: I had hoped that one key can be associated with only one value. So, this is normal behavior when a key is actually a lot of bindings?

Comment: @psct If you're using `HashMultiMap` than one key can be associated with multiple values (that's why it's called `Multi`). If you want to associate one value with a key, then you can use normal F# immutable `Map` or mutable .NET `Dictionary`.